# JSP compile error on WAS 8.5.5 on Linux (works as expected on Windows)

Tags: linux, jsp, websphere, websphere-8, maximo

I have a strange behaviour on Webshphere 8.5.5.13 on Linux.

I have extended a large Enterprise application (IBM Maximo Enterprise Asset Management 7.6.0.9) and added some classes and a JSP file.

These changes work fine on Webshere on Windows (and Weblogic) for months for a lot of customers.
Now we have a customer who has deployed this Enterprise Application on Linux and here are unexpected problems.

When accessing my simple JSP on Linux I get the following error message in the SystemOut.log of the application server:

```
[8/28/18 16:16:06:336 CEST] 00000633 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/ctgAppSrv01/logs/ffdc/MXServer_79a40fc5_18.08.28_16.16.06.3072776788115294465046.txt com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp 259
[8/28/18 16:16:06:337 CEST] 00000633 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp]: com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0049E: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp failed to compile :

JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 3 in the file: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/ctgAppSrv01/temp/ctgNode01/MXServer/MAXIMO/maximouiweb.war/webclient/common/_eamdmtrequesthandler.java : 7 : The import de cannot be resolved

JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 8 in the file: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/ctgAppSrv01/temp/ctgNode01/MXServer/MAXIMO/maximouiweb.war/webclient/common/_eamdmtrequesthandler.java : 87 : ExportXLS cannot be resolved to a type

JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 8 in the file: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /webclient/common/eamdmtrequesthandler.jsp

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/ctgAppSrv01/temp/ctgNode01/MXServer/MAXIMO/maximouiweb.war/webclient/common/_eamdmtrequesthandler.java : 87 : ExportXLS cannot be resolved to a type

        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:616)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:477)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:298)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:167)
```

Facts:

- All required classes are available in their correct folder.  I have checked the EAR file and the installedApps folder in Websphere.
- All files are readable and accessible. No permission issues. Websphere is running as root, SELinux is disabled
- The same EAR file, which has this error on Linux, does not have this problem if deployed under Windows.
- I get the same error message when I try to compile the JSP with the JspBatchCompiler.sh  command from the commandline.
- I have moved my classes from de.eam.webclient.servlet to psdi.webclient.servlet (an already existing package which is part of Maximo) and then the JSP works as expected.

I have checked the log file MXServer_79a40fc5_18.08.28_16.16.06.3072776788115294465046.txt  and I have also verified, that the classpath contains my classes in my folder.

What can be the reason for Websphere not finding my top level package directory "de" and not finding the classes even if they are in the classpath and are found on Windows.

What can I do to track this down?  Is this a bug in Websphere on Linux?

The JSP File:

```
<%@ page language="java"
%><%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
%><%@ page import="de.eam.webclient.servlet.ExportXLS"
%><%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

ExportXLS servlet = new ExportXLS();
servlet.handleRequest(request, response);
%>
```

Comment: Can you try the batch compiler: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rweb_jspbchtl.html

Comment: I have stated in my OP above that I have already done that and that I get the same error message.

Comment: Is the formatting showing here correct, with the linefeeds wrapping the `<%` statements onto the next lines? Almost makes me wonder if it's a character set/linefeed issue in the file itself.

Comment: Yes, the formatting is correct. No, it has nothing to do with linefeeds or charset. This file works on Windows as it should and looks like hundrets of other JSP files in the same project. You might have not understood my problem.

The reason for the placement of the tags is so that the JSP is not generating any newlines in front of the real output which is generated by the java class . You see this quite often.

Comment: Ok, just checking. I'd open a PMR with IBM Support. Seems like you've isolated pretty well.

Comment: @WolfgangFiedler Apologies on not reading every detail. I agree with Doug that official support channels are the best option as it looks like tracing will be required to isolate the issue.

Comment: IBM Support is sometimes very complicated to deal with. We are a IBM Business Partner for Maximo Enterprise Asset Management. We opened a PMR for this problem and guess what the reaction is: 
".....remind you that customization issue is not a support scope by PW PMR services....."
I have also posted the issue on the IBM developerworks forum and I will also try https://www.ibm.com/support/home/